# Symmetric matrix in $\mathbb{Z}_{2}$× $\mathbb{Z}_{2}$

Tags: linear-algebra

assume that $A_{n×n}$ is a symmetric matrix which all entries is in $\mathbb{Z}_{2}$
and all enteries of main diagonal is equal to 1.
prove that there is a vector, name 'v' in $\mathbb{Z}_{2}^{n}$ such thath A×v is equal to the vector of all ones in $\mathbb{Z}_{2}^{n}$.

Is there any generalization of problem for $\mathbb{Z}_{k}$?

Can we get a vector which it doesn't have any zero entery in $\mathbb{Z}_{2}^{n}$ from a symmetric matrix which is diagonal is all one?

Comment: If it generalizes it doesn't do so in an obvious way; consider $\left[\begin{array}{cc}1 & 2\\2 & 1\end{array}\right]$ in $F_3$ for instance.

Comment: what if all entries of A is from set {0,1} ?